# Can't connect to MySQL from Visual studio

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I try to connect to a remote mysql database from VB.NET but i can't figure out how to setup the server because i can;t establish a connection.
I opened the port 3306, which is accessible with telnet, and the message is "unable to connect to any specified hosts"
The code is very simple

```
    MyConn.ConnectionString = "server=" & server & ";" & "database=" & mysqldb & ";" & "uid=" & username & ";" & "password=" & pwd & ";charset=utf8"
    MyConn.Open()
```

The username is a user with % everyhost and the same connection is ok when i running from localhost
Can you help me?

Comment: Please, post the complete code.

Comment: Are you sure the connection string is right? Also, did you try to connect to your server with (for example) MySQL Workbench? Does that work?

Comment: this is the code.Is there anything wrong with the connection string?

Answer (score 0):

I've added the
;Allow Zero Datetime=True
and now is connecting fine
Thanks a lot